# Find a parallel plane that contains a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of a plane that is parallel to the plane
$5x-3y+2z=10$ and contains the line

$x=t+4$
$y=3t-2$
$z=5-2t$

My attempt resulted in failure.
Setting the directional vector: $v = <1,3,-2>$
and the normal vector: $n = <5,-3,2>$

The dot product of $v$ and $n$ should be equal to zero, no? I'm not sure if my algebra is wrong, but how do I finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is doomed to result in failure, I'm afraid. (You're correct that the dot product should be $0$, and isn't, as written.)

Consider any plane parallel to the original plane--that is, a plane of the form $$5x-3y+2z=\alpha\tag{$\star$}$$ for some constant $\alpha.$ Setting $x=t+4,y=3t-2,z=5-2t$ in $(\star)$ gives us $$5(t+4)-3(3t-2)+2(5-2t)=\alpha\\5t+20-9t+6+10-4t=\alpha\\-8t+36=\alpha,$$ which has a unique solution $t$ for *all* real $\alpha.$ Hence, the line intersects *every* plane parallel to the original in *exactly* one point, and so there is no parallel plane that contains the line.

I suspect that perhaps the original plane is supposed to be $$5x-3y-2z=10,$$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it is enough to find a plane that is parallell to the given one containing one point of the given line (take t=0, for example). This plane either contains the whole line or it doesn't - if it does we're done, if not no such plane can be found.

Comment: oh i see, so it contains at least a point of the line. so when $t=0, P(4,-2,5)$ how do I obtain the other 2 points needed? I plug in P to the plane and setup another point with t=1?

Comment: @Pifagor: ***If*** there is a plane parallel to the given one that contains the given line, ***then*** all we have to do is find a parallel plane that meets the line. However, this is not sufficient in this case. See my answer.

Comment: You're quite right. The condition that it contain the whole line just seems a bit redundant in either case.